# how to start a plain text http2 communication directly?

Tags: netty

I am using netty client, and I'm sure the server support http/2. Can I start a plain text http/2 request directly? I don't want to send a http/1.1 request, and upgrade to http/2 with 101 return code.

Comment: What error message do you get when you try?

Comment: I just follow the example:
DefaultFullHttpRequest upgradeRequest =
                    new DefaultFullHttpRequest(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.GET, "/");
ctx.writeAndFlush(upgradeRequest);

It seems that there is no "HttpVersion.HTTP_2_0".

If I set a buffer with magic word: "PRI...":
ctx.writeAndFlush(Http2CodecUtil.connectionPrefaceBuf());
Nothing will be sent.

Comment: As far as I know http/2 is only available via TLS because the only way to establish a connection works via ALPN (Application-Layer Protocol Negotiation) which is an extension to TLS.

Comment: http/2 can run over plain text. Infact I have done it. I just want to skip: http/1.1 request,  response 101 (Switching Protocols).

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is known as 'h2c with prior knowledge': the client already knows the server supports HTTP/2 and can directly start talking HTTP/2 without first negotiating.

Not all servers support this, and some will require opening up a separate port specifically for this purpose.

I'm not sure how to configure the Netty client to do this, but you could look at the sources for the Netty gRPC client (https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/netty/src/main/java/io/grpc/netty) for inspiration: this client can be configured to directly start talking HTTP/2 by choosing `NegotiationType.PLAINTEXT`.